# org-babel source block language specifier issue

Tags: org-babel

I've installed [j-mode](https://github.com/zellio/j-mode) and it works.

But in an org-babel code block I have a strange issue.

Spelling like `begin_src J` (capital J) allows me to evaluate the block, but has no syntax highlighting:

```
#+begin_src J
(+/%#) 0.2 + i.24  NB. avg
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 11.7
```

Also, I can't use `C-c '` to edit the code in a popup; instead I get an error message: `No such language mode: J-mode`.

Here's the strangest thing: when I change the spelling to `begin_src j` (lowercase j), then I get syntax highlighting and can use `C-c '` to edit the code in a popup as expected.

However, now org-babel won't evaluate the source block, and when I try it complains with `ob-j.elc failed to provide feature ‘ob-j’`.

Is there anything I can do to get both sets of features at the same time?

Comment: `ob-j.elc failed to provide feature ‘ob-j’` sounds strange - maybe ob-j.elc is corrupt or needs to be recompiled?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. I think org-babel uses `ob-J` (uppercase) but org's own syntax highlighting uses `j-mode` (lowercase).

Comment: I have `ob-J.elc` but no `ob-j.elc`. Will try a recompile.

Comment: ob-J.el ends with `(provide 'ob-J)`. Should I edit it so it says `(provide 'ob-j)` instead?

Comment: I wonder how `ob-C.el` and `c-mode` coexist. If there is a trick there, it might be applied to `ob-J.el`. You might want to bring it up on the Org mode mailing list.

Comment: How about adding `(defalias 'J-mode 'j-mode)` at the beginning of `ob-J.el`? Does that make it all work?

Comment: @NickD I tried adding the alias like you suggested: no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this in your init file:

```
(add-to-list 'org-src-lang-modes '("J" . j))
```

that should allow you to edit and give you syntax highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Found a hacky workaround. A the bottom of `.emacs.d/.local/straight/repos/org/lisp/ob-J.el`, I added a line:

```
(provide 'ob-J)
(provide 'ob-j) ;; this line added by me
```

Now everything works as expected. Seems dumb that this is necessary though.